# Passing data to React component through Laravel blade

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel

I don't know if this is even possible or maybe this is just a stupid question, but here it goes:

Is it possible to pass data from you Laravel controller to a React Component through a blade template?

I'm asking this because I have a form where I have three static form elements (`name`, `description` & `deadline`) that are defined in blade and a dynamic part that adds elements (extra fields; `name`, `description` and `type` for each extra `field`) to the form on a button click.

I also want to use the component for editing, so I need to push data into it. My train of thought was to use React for the dynamic part so that I don't have to use native JS or jQuery to build this.

Note that I'm a beginner at React so I this point I don't even know if I'm doing it right/wrong. I've added a screenshot of the form to show illustrate what I mean. (sorry it's in Dutch but I've tried to add some notes to make it clear)[image]

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#displaying-data) maybe will help you out:

under Rendering json ..

This is how `vuejs` works. Your controller would return a variable like `$project` and you would pass it as a prop into your component by using `@json($project)`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply! Tried to use it for react but didn't work. I see now that this is indeed the solution for vuejs. Do you have any experience with it? Is it better/easier than react?

Comment: Well, that's a impossible question to answer... because better is a difficult thing to define. I already worked with angular2 and vuejs, never with react and in my humble perspective I like vuejs more simply because it is super raw. Also, Laravel bundles vuejs with its own framework and that's why it's a good match, after all you get support out of the box.

Comment: Alright, then maybe it's time for me to check out vue.js. Thansk for the answer and your time @nullisnotundefined !